# 7TV installed itself on AppleTV 4K

Tags: appletv

I just opened my AppleTV 4K and I found an app called 7TV installed!

Any ideas how that could happen?

I never downloaded it.

Location is Germany

Comment: I've had several Apple TVs for years and not once has an app installed itself.  Are you sure you, or someone in your household, didn't install this by accident?  This is supposed to be a legit app from ProSiebenSat.1.

Comment: @fsb yes I’m so sure. I live alone. I never hear about 7TV before.

Comment: I experience the same issue! The app installed itself, and is not even listed under “Manage storage” in general settings.
Seems like it’s another U2 incident on Apple’s part, or they are just offering it as a service-type application.
I am located in Germany as well. To respond to suggestions by others: auto-download is off, didn’t install any tv provider app on other devices and nobody but me has access to my Apple ID.

Answer (score -1):

On tvOS 10 and later you can enable the feature called "Automatic Downloads" - it sounds like this is what you did.

When "Automatic Downloads" is on, the Apple TV will automatically install apps that you have on your iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch, that are compatible with Apple TV. The key is that the same Apple ID account is added to the Apple TV as you have used on another device.

Comment: I know the behaviour of iOS. I never installed 7TV on any on my devices before. I didn't know about it in the first place. Looks like AppleTV 4K installed it by itself as part of ProSiebenSat.1 campaign in Germany.

Comment: The AppleTV4k does not by itself install apps - not even part of a ProSieben campaign. However, note that the may be called "7TV" on the AppleTV, but the app could have a different name on your iPhone, even though it is the same (universal) app. If you still claim you didn't install it, someone else probably had access to your AppleTV and did.